# React-Native Redux this.props undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux

I am trying to use Redux to display data from firebase DB but for some reason this.props is undefined 
I used redux to display another data in another pages from my DB with no problems.But here I stuck and can't find my mistake

Here is my code.I hope someone can give me advice what is wrong here

in my invoice.js I have :

```
    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
return {
    startFireData: state.startFireData,

};
    }

    const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
return {
    watchInvoiceStartFire: () => { dispatch(watchInvoiceStartFire()) },
};
    }

    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.props.watchInvoiceStartFire();
     }
```

and in Render:

```
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <LinearGradient
                colors={['#3399ff', '#66b3ff', '#cccccc']}
                style={styles.pageStyle}>
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}  >{this.props.startFireData.נפיץ}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}  >{this.props.startFireData.עשן_חדש}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}  >{this.props.startFireData.עשן_ישן}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}  >דוחות</Text>
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}  >דוחות</Text>
            </LinearGradient>
        </View>
```

in my redux file:

```
    const watchInvoiceStartFire = () =>{
return function(dispatch) {
    firebase.database().ref("Invoices/startfire/ammo").on("value", function(snapshot) {
        var startFireData = snapshot.val();
        dispatch(setStartFireData(startFireData));
    }, function(error) { });
};
    }

    const setStartFireData = (startFireData) =>{
return {
    type: "setStartFireData",
    value: startFireData
}
    }

    const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
switch(action.type) {
    case "setStorageData":
        return { ...state, storageData: action.value };

    case "setOperationData":
        return {...state, operationData: action.value};

    case "setStartFireData":
        return {...state, startFireData: action.value};

    default:
        return state;
}
    };
```

My mistake,I forgot to add to initial state

```
    const initialState = {
personData: { },
storageData:{ },
operationData:{ },
startFireData:{ },
```

};

Sorry for bothering u here

Comment: Are you connecting state and dispatch with redux? That isn't clear from your code paste

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question

Comment: You're created `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` functions, but I can't see the part where you actually connect them with `connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ComponentName);`

Comment: They are connected and now all works.I just forgot to add initial state.Thx anyway